# Is flask using HTTPS or HTTP?

Tags: python, flask, ssl, http-post

I managed to create self signed certificate using mkcert and sign it as CA so my pc sees this certificate as trusted.Mkcert created two files *'localhost.pem'* and *'localhost-key.pem'* and I refer to them when running flask app. When I launch flask app using `flask --app=server run --cert=localhost.pem --key=localhost-key.pem --debug` it shows thar server is running as https(image below).
[image]

I can access this website using browser and it is in fact https.
I wanted to access the server with python script using requests module and it worked but there is one thing that interests me. It is fact that console shows log as [image]
As you can see there is HTTP/1.1 not HTTPS.

#### Question:Are things sent by request between client and server secured by https or not?

If I try to print `request.is_secure` in flask it returns True, when I print `request.scheme` it returns https so it looks like it is secured but I am not sure because of the flask log as HTTP/1.1

#### client.py

```
import requests

data={'username':'pamix'}
r = requests.post(url='https://localhost:5000/test',data=data)
```

#### server.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test",methods=['POST'])
def test():
    print(f"is_secure:{request.is_secure}")
    print(f"scheme:{request.scheme}")

    return 'test'

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see there is HTTP/1.1 not HTTPS

HTTPS is the HTTP protocol inside the TLS authentication+encryption. The protocol version is still HTTP/1.1, i.e. there is no HTTPS/1.1.

Comment: so based on fact that ```request.is_secure``` returns True and ```request.scheme``` returns "https" I can presume that connection is via https and in fact is secure, am I right?

Comment: ```request.url``` starts with 'https' so I guess its indeed https,thanks.